# DataGridView - finding current row

Tags: vb.net

Got a DGV populated by a database.  I want to find the value of a cell on the first row when the DGV's form is shown and also a value of a selected rows cell when a user selects another row.

I've used the RowEnter event but it seems to get invoked when the form opens and gives me an error.  If I try to collect a cells data when the RowIndex >0 then it works but I cant pick up a value from the top row.

```
Private Sub dgvOrders_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvOrders.RowEnter
  If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    txtOrderNumber.Text = dgvOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString
  End If
end sub
```

I can see in the doc that the event is called when the DGV is initally loaded.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Am I using the right event for this?
Is there something wrong in my code?
What is the best way of doing what i'm trying to do?!

Right thanks to all that helped.  This is what I did.  I didn't need to set the selectionMode of the DGV to anything but the default.  I did need to know when a user changed the row he was looking at so needed to put the code into the "SelectionChanged" event of the DGV.

In the end I gave up and bodged it by checking if the value returned by the dgvOrders.currentrow.cells(1).value isnt nothing before calling a sub that populates the text box fields on the form with values obtained from the current row.

```
    Private Sub dgvOrders_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvOrders.SelectionChanged

        Try
            If Not dgvOrders.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing Then
                populateFields()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
         'catch code here
        End Try
End sub
```

I'm not sure if I should mark any responses as the answer but the all assisted me in getting to this point.  If there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: *"Am I using the right event for this?"* That depends when you want to do it. The `RowEnter` event is raised every time the caret enters a different row. Is that when you want to do whatever it is that you want to do? If not then you're using the wrong event. If you want to do it when the user clicks a `Button` then you need to handle the `Click` event of that `Button`. Etc. You need to decide what the specific circumstances are under which you want to act and then choose the event that is raised under those circumstances.

Comment: Hans - I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned Nothing.

which is probably because its being called before the DGV has any values in it

Comment: jmcilhinney - I want to pull a values from cells in any row thats selected.  When the form comes up I want to be able to collect the cell values from the top row.   So its when a user clicks on the row, not a button.  I hope that makes sense. :-)

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I've managed to catch the error by only finding the currentrow.cells(1).value when this is true "If Not dgvOrders.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing Then".  
This stops the error and produces a value when a user selects a row but doesnt pick up the value in the first row initially.  I guess I could programmatically  trigger the selection changed event when form has loaded and the dgv is populated.  Seems really convoluted .

Comment: @Hans I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned Nothing. which is probably because its being called before the DGV has any values in it

Answer (score 0):

If you want click on the row header try

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick
    MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString)

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may work, it is encouraged to have more context in your answer such as why this code works, or why the problem was occurring so that the OP and other users can understand the causes without asking further questions. Please add more to your answer.

Comment: Sorry I dont want the row header.  I want to obtain cell values of the currently selected row.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
Private Sub dgvOrders_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvOrders.RowEnter
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        txtOrderNumber.Text = dgvOrders.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
    End If
End sub
```

And make sure *dgvOrders.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect*

Comment: Thanks.  That would pull a value, but it wouldnt update if a user changed the row, only when I ran that line of code if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, this would get the [current row - cell 1] value and put it on txtOrderNumber textbox on every row change.

Comment: Jortx - sorry I dont understand.  If I put this code in the form load event, how would it update if the user changed the row?

Comment: I tried your code using the DGV's .SelectionChanged event and got this error.  "Index was out of range.  Must be non-negative and less thatn the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Comment: @user3844416 - You also must check for e.RowIndex >= 0 and ensure the DataGridView.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect . If you do so, you should not get the error message...